# Unable to update a react-redux state properly (array)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following state update function for a redux array

```
if (replace) {
    return {
      ...state,
      mySelectionOtrosFiltros: items
    }
  } else {
    return {
      ...state,
      mySelectionOtrosFiltros: state.mySelectionOtrosFiltros.concat(a[0])
    }
  }
```

If replace is false, the state update works properly, and I can see it being updated.

But if repace is true, i want to substitute `mySelectionOtrosFiltros` which is an array of objects, completly by a new array of objects named `items`

But that case isnt working.

I can see state.mySelectionOtrosFiltros being updated, but its not rerendered so i guess im messing up the inmutability. It will only be rendered properly if i trigger the else statement , in that case the new element is added and the previous updates are now displayed.

example of non working case

```
mySelectionOtrosFiltros = [{a: 1 , b: 2, c: 3}]

items = [{a: 2, b: 2, c: 2},{a:4 , b: 4, c: 4}]
```

myselectionotrosfiltros should be replaced with items completly, so it looks like items

```
return {
      ...state,
      mySelectionOtrosFiltros: items
    }
```

it doesnt get replaced

Comment: We can't answer that without knowing how you calculate `items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to share full code in order to really pin which parts of the code violated immutability.

having that said you can still do a quick try by creating a new copy of `items` as below

```js
if (replace) {
    return {
      ...state,
      mySelectionOtrosFiltros: [...items]
    }
  }
```

If indeed its due to mutation, the above code should fix your issue